# Converting Geographic Coordinates into Lambert2008 coordinates

Tags: c#, geospatial

This is part of a game made in Unity3D.

I wrote this class to convert geographic coordinates into lambert 2008 coordinates based on this reference document:

http://www.ngi.be/Common/Lambert2008/Transformation_Geographic_Lambert_FR.pdf

Reason is that I'm using a Belgian National Geographic Institute map as background, and want to locate waypoint and player position with full accuracy.

Code works fine, and runs in .000001s but I'm unhappy with its readability.

I start by declaring all the constants I need

```
public const int a = 6378137;
public const double f = 1 / 298.257222101;
public const double lowerLatitude = 49.8333333 * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
public const double upperLatitude = 51.1666667 * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
public const double originLatitude = 50.797815 * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
public const double originLongitude = 4.359215833 * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
public const int originX = 649328;
public const int originY = 665262;
```

Then  I used properties for all values derived from those constants

```
public static double Excentricity {get => System.Math.Sqrt((2 * f) - (f * f));}

static double MLower { get => M(lowerLatitude);}
static double MUpper { get => M(upperLatitude);}

static double M(double latitude)
{
    return System.Math.Cos(latitude) / System.Math.Sqrt(1 - (Excentricity * Excentricity * System.Math.Pow(System.Math.Sin(latitude), 2)));
}

static double TLower { get => T(lowerLatitude); }
static double TUpper { get => T(upperLatitude); }
static double TOrigin { get => T(originLatitude); }

static double T(double latitude)
{

    return System.Math.Tan(Mathf.PI / 4 - latitude / 2) / System.Math.Pow((1 - Excentricity * System.Math.Sin(latitude)) / (1 + Excentricity * System.Math.Sin(latitude)), Excentricity / 2);
}

static double N { get => (System.Math.Log(MLower) - System.Math.Log(MUpper)) / (System.Math.Log(TLower) - System.Math.Log(TUpper)); }

static double G { get => MLower / (N * System.Math.Pow(TLower, N)); }

static double ROrigin { get => R(TOrigin); }

static double R (double t)
{
    return a * G * System.Math.Pow(t, N);
}
```

As you can see some of the calculations are written on very long lines. I'm unhappy with their readability, but I have no Idea on how to re-write them to make them look better while not messing up floating point approximations.

Finally I perform the actual conversion using all those calculated values.

```
public static Vector2 FromGeographicRelative(Vector2 coordinates)
{

    double t = T((double)coordinates.x * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    double r = R(t);
    double angle = N * ((double)coordinates.y * Mathf.Deg2Rad - originLongitude);
    Vector2 lambertCoord = new Vector2
    {
        x = (float) (r * System.Math.Sin(angle)),
        y = (float) (ROrigin - r * System.Math.Cos(angle))
    };
    return lambertCoord;

}
```

Comment: There are libraries for coordinate projection. GDAL and ProjNet, for examples. However, .NET is admittedly one of the worst (if not the worst) language for geospatial tools. They tend to be fairly poorly maintained.

Comment: @jpmc26 what is the point of your comment? Is this the usual _don't implement anything yourself_ or are we this time _allowed_ to make an exception because those libraries are poorly maintained?

Comment: @t3chb0t It's about being practical and not wasting time. A library used more widely than your own code and written by people who deal with this field regularly also has less chance of containing bugs. But if the projection is newer (which it isn't) or if it's buggy in those or doesn't support changing parameters needed (which they do support many), then using it isn't practical.

Comment: @t3chb0t As an aside, taking things personally and being dismissive of good advice is unprofessional.

Comment: @jpmc26 Thanks for the info, geospatial localisation is completely new to me, I knew nothing about it 2 days ago, so I didn't know where to look. I very quickly found that reference document with all the formulas I needed to achieve exactly what I wanted, so I didn't even bother looking for a full blown library when I knew I could easily implement it myself. The Belgian National Geographic Institute does provide a windows .dll for conversions, but this has to work on iOS so using their .dll was not an option. I don't like to use a full blown library if I'm only going to use 0.0001% of it

Comment: @user1747281 I generally try not to worry about how much of a library I'm using. Often times, you find that as the application expands, you'll end up using more of it anyway. That said, I understand that you have to be more concerned about disk space with a mobile app. Additionally, geospatial libraries in non-native runtimes (e.g., .NET and Python) are often built on top of native binaries that wouldn't port to iOS easliy anyway. (GDAL is primarily a set of native binaries with some .NET and Python wrappers.) So they may not work for your use case. Good luck.

Comment: Did you write tests for your conversion? The corresponding EPSG code is 3812, so you can check if your input values are correct here : https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/etrs89-belgian-lambert-2008/html/ and use this website: https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=3812&t_srs=3857 in order to manually create test pairs for your conversion.

Comment: I run a test with 5 coordinates: brussels, genk, de panne, bastogne and chimay. I used [this tool](http://zoologie.umons.ac.be/tc/conversions.aspx) to determine the target values (uses the official NGI SOAP API). My result is exactly the expected result at every location.

Comment: @user1747281 I would add tests for boundary cases (such as the origin, the northern, southern, eastern, and western extremities, along with the corners which are intersections of extremities) and error cases as well. Longitudes outside of [-180,180] and latitudes outside of [-90,90] should definitely be tested, whether they should error out (probably) or do something else.

Comment: @jpmc26 origin is tested as well. The 5 locations are more or less center, N, E S, W. At -90, 90 I get NaN but no actual execution error. But those are just unit tests, I have yet to make a functional test with "weird" coordinates. Unity will definitely throw an error when I try to set the position of my object at NaN coordinates on the scene.

Comment: @jpmc26: As far as I know, the bounding box of a coordinate reference system isn't a hard limit. Results are considered to be "good enough" and "accurate enough" inside, but they can be calculated outside without any exception.

Comment: @EricDuminil Many coordinate systems have divergence problems if they are extended to the poles (+/-90 degrees). Consider web mercator, which maps to a rectangle. If you allowed it to go all the way to the north pole, what point on the top of the rectangle would it map to? The formulae uses tangent to compute the `y` coordinate, and it diverges at 90°. Intuitively, if you follow the pattern of the map, you would expect the poles to require an *infinite* amount of distortion to map them to a line. Web mercator avoids these problems by defining its north/south boundaries at +/-85.05°.

Comment: @EricDuminil Notice that this set of formulae also uses tangent. It diverges at +/-90° as well. So I would expect it to have a limit on the valid longitudes.

Comment: @jpmc26: For this specific case, the boundaries seem to be : 2.5400, 49.5100, 6.4000, 51.5000 (https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/etrs89-belgian-lambert-2008/). You're right that `tan` could pose a problem for other coordinates, but fortunately, Belgium is at a safe distance from the North Pole.

Comment: Belgian Lambert2008 being a conical projection, it doesn't make much sense to allow for conversion of coordinates beyond certain bounds. What would be the best practice for that? Throw an OutOfBoundsException when the coordinates are outside of specific bounds? Invoke an event? Or just ignore it altogether and let the caller figure out if he's doing nonsense.

Comment: @user1747281 Barring extraordinary circumstances, an exception would be the simplest means, as well as the normal one. You'll need to make sure that whatever code invokes this conversion has a way to catch exceptions and have the program respond appropriately (even if "appropriately" just means reporting an error to the user and then crashing), but you need that anyway to guard against bugs. (Who knows what inputs might generate an unanticipated null reference exception?)

Comment: TIL: C# doesn't have checked exceptions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> public const double lowerLatitude = 49.8333333 * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
> ```

Huh? `Mathf.Deg2Rad` is a `float`. Either use `Math.PI / 180` or change the type of `lowerLatitude` to `float`, but don't work with low-precision values and then implicitly claim that the result is high-precision.

---

> ```
> static double MLower { get => M(lowerLatitude);}
> ```

This (and all the other similar lines) is weird. I can understand using the old-style

```
static double MLower { get { return M(lowerLatitude); } }
```

or the new-style

```
static double MLower => M(lowerLatitude);
```

but the only reason I can see to use the hybrid form is if there's also a setter.

---

Actually, I think there's a better way to handle derived constants. If you use `static readonly` fields and a static constructor, the calculation only has to be done once and the methods which you created to share the code can be hidden inside a private scope. Following t3chb0t's comments on variable names:

```
static readonly double E = System.Math.Sqrt((2 - f) * f);

static readonly double M1;
static readonly double M2;

static readonly double T1;
static readonly double T2;
static readonly double T0;

static readonly double N;
static readonly double G;
static readonly double R0;

static YourClassNameHere()
{
    (double, double) MT(double ϕ)
    {
        double cosϕ = System.Math.Cos(ϕ);
        double e_sinϕ = E * System.Math.Sin(ϕ);
        double m = cosϕ / System.Math.Sqrt(1 - System.Math.Pow(e_sinϕ, 2));
        double t = System.Math.Tan(Mathf.PI / 4 - ϕ / 2) / System.Math.Pow((1 - e_sinϕ) / (1 + e_sinϕ), E / 2);
        return (m, t);
    }

    double _;
    (_, T0) = MT(ϕ0);
    (M1, T1) = MT(ϕ1);
    (M2, T2) = MT(ϕ2);

    N = System.Math.Log(M1 / M2, T1 / T2);
    G = M1 / (N * System.Math.Pow(T1, N));
    R0 = a * G * System.Math.Pow(T0, N);
}
```

Note that I've also refactored `N` to an algebraically equivalent expression (\$\log(x/y)=\log x - \log y\$ and \$\log_b x = \log x / \log b\$) and verified that the result is the same.

---

And as a minor point of spelling: in English the non-circularity of an ellipse is *eccentricity* with a double-*c*, reduced from the *-xc-* of its etymology.

Comment: I didn't have time to rewrite the formula completely but it looks really nice now, with the original mathematical symbols! One improvement though about `(double, double) MT(double ϕ)` - I would give these two names like `(double M, double T)` etc... or actually it doesn't really matter since you deconstruct them anyway.

Comment: @t3chb0t, it's a shame that Unicode subscript numbers aren't also valid in identifiers.

Comment: `static readonly` seems the best option to me. Simple built-in solution without the need for Lazy, memoization or T4.

Comment: You're absolutely right about Deg2Rad, it's legacy from when I initially used UnityEngine.Mathf before switching to System.Math.

For the getter syntax, it's the auto-generated code from VS. It generates a property with getter and setter, and I just removed the setter part. Thanks for clarifying this, point taken, lesson learned.

Thanks a lot for the refactored code, looks sexy. Looking at it, I can't believe I've not thought of doing it that way from the start. Sometimes the simplest solutions just elude us for some reason.

Comment: @PeterTaylor They are available with unicode escape sequence: \u00B2 is ² Depending on your IDE, the variable name can be dispayed nicely.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled about this line: `N = System.Math.Log(M1 / M2, T1 / T2);` are you sure this translate into the same as `N = (Log(M1) - Log(M2))/(Log(T1)-Log(T2))` ?

Comment: @PeterTaylor brilliant. Haven't worked much with logs since 12th grade. Do you mind if I edit your answer with that extra bit of explanation?

Comment: @PeterTaylor one more question: any reason why MT is declared inside the constructor? I need to calculate T and R inside my "FromGeographicRelative" method. Is there any problem if I move the method declaration outside the constructor?

Comment: @user1747281, sorry, my mistake. I was trying to use the smallest possible scope, and I overlooked that `T` was used elsewhere.

Comment: Don't be sorry, made me learn something new :-)

Answer (score 10):

Since the code is about implementing mathematical formulas I would make an exception and completely ignore the usual naming conventions. Instead, I would use the exact symbols as  that document.

This would mean a little bit copy/paste because it's difficult to write symbols like [`ϕ`, `λ`, `θ`] but the [compiler can work with unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837738/is-it-wrong-to-use-special-characters-in-c-sharp-source-code-such-as-%C3%B1).

I find that code like this:

```
var rad = 0.01745329252;

var ellipsoide = (a: 6378137, f: 1 / 298.257222101);
var ϕ1 = 49.8333333 * rad;
var ϕ2 = 51.1666667 * rad;
var ϕ0 = 50.797815 * rad;
var λ0 = 4.359215833 * rad;
var x0 = 649328;
var y0 = 665262;
```

is the most easy one to understand because you can compare it with the book almost without any *translation*.

Comment: Oh, that's awesome, I didn't know the compiler accepted special characters like this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would just write `phi1` and `lambda1`. Anyone reasonably familiar with math or physics will know what that means.

Comment: @jpmc26 hahaha I knew sooner or later you would say that ;-)

Comment: I should use unicode more often in my code, it can look awesome. Honest question : Is `var` a good idea, since OP seems to be mixing floats and doubles?

Comment: @EricDuminil I think it's ok here becuase `double` is the default for `0.1` and OP is doing all their calculations with `double` and only for the final creation of the `Vector2` values are casted to `float`.

Comment: @t3chb0t: See comment about `Mathf.Deg2Rad` in the accepted answer.

Comment: I never use type inference in my code, always thought it was a bad practice to avoid at all costs. Perhaps I should reconsider.

Comment: @user1747281 if it was a _bad_ practice, I don't think they would have given us this feature that I think is a **huge** timesaver. On the contrary, I find always defining types explicitly is a bad practice because it makes the code extremely verbose and you see more type definitions than you can see the actual logic which makes reading code much harder.

Comment: small noob question: I refactored my code entirely with all the good advice given from everyone. Should / could I post my refactored code for a post-facelift-review in this trhead?

Comment: @user1747281 you have two options 1) post either a self-answer in this thread (less reviewable, only via comments but if you think it's final then it'd be the way to go 2) or you can post a follow-up question if you think there is still something _signifficant_ to improve. What you must not do, is to edit the current question and add the improved version there.

Comment: @user1747281 Regarding type inference, I wouldn't say avoid it at all costs. I would just say use it wisely. In this case, the `double`/`float` confusion might be a good reason to be explicit; declaring it explicitly helped someone realize you had a small precision bug in your code. But when you have a `var something = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()`, repeating all that in the variable declaration doesn't buy you much. It just depends on whether noting the type name has any benefit or not for your particular situation.

Comment: Minor nitpick: ϕ0 is defined in the specs as "50° 47’52”134", so it's might be a good idea to use `50 + 47.0 / 60 + 52.134 / 3600` instead of `50.797815`. A typo such as `50.979815` would be hard to spot.

Answer (score 4):

- In *math heavy* code you might use the `using static` directive, see the [microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) such that `System.Math.` can be removed throughout the code.
- `Excentricity` can be made a constant and may have a shorter name as I have seen in other codes dealing with WGS84.
- If possible refer to a document and formula number in a comment
- Although sometime frowned on, I like to layout the the code as much as possible as the mathematical equation looks like. (use extra parentheses if it improves readability)

With this in mind I came to to following example for method `T`.

```
using static System.Math;

public const double E2 = (2 * f) - (f * f);  # Excentricity squared
public const double E1 = Sqrt(E2);           # Excentricity

.....

    static double T(double lat)
    {
        // if possible refer to a document and formula number
        return  Tan(PI / 4 - lat / 2) 
                / 
                Pow( ((1 - E1 * Sin(lat)) 
                      / 
                      (1 + E1 * Sin(lat))) , E1 / 2);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot for these hints.
I'm deliberately not using "using System.Math" because this code is part of a game made with Unity3D. 
Typically, Unity programmers would use UnityEngine.Mathf, which is a wrapper class for System.Math using floats instead of doubles (because game engines like floats better). So to make it more obvious I explicitly prefix my math calls with System.Math (perhaps a bad practice, would be happy to have your opinion on this)
Thanks for the excentricity tip, will definitely do that.

Comment: You can add a using directive: `using Math = System.Math`

Comment: @user1747281 I am not familiar with Unity programmers conventions, but `using static UnityEngine.Mathf` might be acceptable, also when using Mathf the constants can be made floats instead of doubles.

Comment: @user1747281 that _this code is part of a game made with Unity3D_ should have been mentioned in the question so that reviewers have enough context how it is used.

Comment: @t3chb0t done, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3):

#### Constants

You have a lot of mathematical constants that aren't constants in your API. Why?

> Excentricity, MLower, MUpper, TLower, TUpper, TOrigin, ROrigin, N, G.

EDIT:

In the comments you suggest that the compiler does not accept these constants. But the problem is not the compiler, it's that **you should not use the formula to declare a constant**. Pre-calculate the constant using [T4](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019) and use the result in your derived constants.

```
// Just paste the pre-calculated result from T4
static double Excentricity = 0.0818191910428158d;
```

A simpler option is to use `static readonly`as Peter suggests in his answer.

#### Naming Conventions

Some, but not all of your variables and functions are named after mathematical usage. I like it either way, but a combination is an inconsistent naming convention.

> ```
> public const double f = 1 / 298.257222101;
> public const double lowerLatitude = 49.8333333 * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
> ```

#### Aliases

You are using both `System.Math` and `UnityEngine.Mathf`. To avoid repeating code I suggest to import the one you used most as a *static using* and the other as an `aliased using`.

```
using static UnityEngine.Mathf;
using Math = System.Math;
```

Comment: **Naming conventions:** I didn't know you could use mathematical symbols in names, so instead of naming the variable "phi1", "phi2" etc... I opted for a purposeful name. But I now know better thanks to this community :-)
**Constants:** I don't understand what you mean. They're not constants, they're derived from constants. 
I tried this:
`public const double Excentricity = System.Math.Sqrt((2 * f) - (f * f));`
but the compiler doesn't accept it because Sqrt((2 * f)-(f*f)) is not a constant.
**Aliases:** I like that idea, thanks for the tip

Comment: See my edit => They are constants, you just need to use the formula to get the result and paste that result in your code :) The problem is not the compiler. You should pre-calculate these constants and put the result in the API. For instance, let's take a very easy example: `const int x = 1 + 1` -> you could also write `const x = 2`

Comment: @PeterTaylor I would favor performance optimization over maintainability here. Specially if I feel mathematical constants tend not to change that often (if ever). But I get your point, and I would use a T4 or other template to be able to recalculate these constants whenever I need to. At least use memoization if you keep the formula for a constant value.

Comment: Ok I get what you mean, and it's probably the best thing to do in my current situation. 
However here was my thought process:
there's not only one set of lambert conical projection base constants. Here I'm just doing the Lambert2008, but I wanted to keep open the possibility of working with different sets of Lambert constants (Lambert72, french lambert, ....).
I could make an excel sheet and calculate excentricity etc whenever I need to do a new set of constants, but it doesn't come across to me as very maintainable code, and if there's a problem with one constant you have to go back to xls

Comment: If you have constants derived from other constants, and you want both performance and maintainability, you should use memoization. Check `Lazy<T>`.

Comment: @dfhwze perhaps I could use some kind of factory to instantiate a "LambertConstants" struct and have a static LambertConstants in my LambertUtils class. Would that make sense?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Check out Peter's answer, he solved it by using `static readonly`, which adheres to both performance and maintainability attributes.

Answer (score 2):

First **thank you all** for your help, and specifically @t3chb0t , @JanKuiken , @PeterTaylor and @dfhwze . I learned a lot today.

Here is the refactored code taking into account all the comments. I think it looks a lot better already.

Not only that but **performance** was multiplied by **20**

```
using static System.Math;
using UnityEngine;

public static class Lambert2008
{
    public const int a = 6378137;
    public const double f = 1 / 298.257222101;
    public const double rad = PI/180;
    public const double ϕ1 = 49.8333333 * rad;
    public const double ϕ2 = 51.1666667 * rad;
    public const double ϕ0 = 50.797815 * rad;
    public const double λ0 = 4.359215833 * rad;
    public const int x0 = 649328;
    public const int y0 = 665262;

    static readonly double E = Sqrt((2 - f) * f);

    static readonly double M1;
    static readonly double M2;

    static readonly double T1;
    static readonly double T2;
    static readonly double T0;

    static readonly double N;
    static readonly double G;
    static readonly double R0;

    static Lambert2008()
    {
        double _;
        (_, T0) = MT(ϕ0);
        (M1, T1) = MT(ϕ1);
        (M2, T2) = MT(ϕ2);

        N = Log(M1 / M2, T1 / T2);
        G = M1 / (N * Pow(T1, N));
        R0 = a * G * Pow(T0, N);
    }

    static (double, double) MT(double ϕ)
    {
        var e_sinϕ = E * Sin(ϕ);
        var m = Cos(ϕ) / Sqrt(1 - Pow(e_sinϕ, 2));
        var t = CalculateT(ϕ);
        return (m, t);
    }

    static double R(double t)
    {
        return a * G * Pow(t, N);
    }

    static double CalculateT(double ϕ)
    {
        var e_sinϕ = E * Sin(ϕ);
        return Tan(PI / 4 - ϕ / 2)
            / Pow((1 - e_sinϕ) / (1 + e_sinϕ), E / 2);
    }

    public static Vector2 FromGeographicRelative(Vector2 coordinates)
    {
        double _, t, r;
        (_, t) = MT(coordinates.x * rad);
        r = R(t);
        var θ = N * (coordinates.y * rad - λ0);
        var res = new Vector2
        {
            x = (float)(r * Sin(θ)),
            y = (float)(R0 - r * Cos(θ))
        };
        return res;
    }

    public static Vector2 FromGeographic(Vector2 coordinates)
    {
        return FromGeographicRelative(coordinates) + new Vector2(x0, y0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Coool! This has become really nice!

Comment: Also, I just tested performance. **10000 calls** to FromGeographicRelative as benchmark. **Before** refactoring: **0.09s**; *After* refactoring: **0.005s** so about **20x performance** gain

Comment: Might as well refactor `MT` back to just `M`. The only reason I combined them in one was to save recalculating `e_sinϕ`.